# Select in NSArray from generated from JSON

Tags: objective-c, multidimensional-array

I have an NSArray created from a JSON file.
If I just Print the Array to the console I get the following output: 
[Click me](http://supertiko300.funpic.de/stackoverflow/arraycontent.rtf).

First part of file:

```
{
    result =     {
        "attribute_controlled_attached_particles" =         (
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 0;
                id = 1;
                name = "Partikel 1";
                system = "burningplayer_red";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 0;
                id = 2;
                name = "Fliegende Teile";
                system = "burningplayer_flyingbits";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 0;
                attachment = muzzle1;
                id = 3;
                name = "Nemesis-Explosion";
                system = "particle_nemesis_burst_blue";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 0;
                id = 4;
                name = "Community-Glitzer";
                system = "community_sparkle";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 0;
                attachment = halopoint1;
                id = 5;
                name = Heiligenschein;
                system = halopoint;
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 0;
                id = 6;
                name = "Gr\U00fcnes Konfetti";
                system = "superrare_confetti_green";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 0;
                id = 7;
                name = "Lila Konfetti";
                system = "superrare_confetti_purple";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                attachment = muzzle;
                id = 8;
                name = "Spukende Geister";
                system = "superrare_ghosts";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                id = 9;
                name = "Gr\U00fcne Energieladung";
                system = "superrare_greenenergy";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                id = 10;
                name = "Lila Energieladung";
                system = "superrare_purpleenergy";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                attachment = muzzle;
                id = 11;
                name = "Kreisendes TF-Logo";
                system = "superrare_circling_tf";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                id = 12;
                name = Fliegenschwarm;
                system = "superrare_flies";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                attachment = muzzle;
                id = 13;
                name = "Brennende Flammen";
                system = "superrare_burning1";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                attachment = unusual;
                id = 14;
                name = "Sengende Flammen";
                system = "superrare_burning2";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                attachment = muzzle;
                id = 15;
                name = "Gl\U00fchendes Plasma";
                system = "superrare_plasma1";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                attachment = muzzle;
                id = 16;
                name = "Lebendiges Plasma";
                system = "superrare_plasma2";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                id = 17;
                name = Sonnenstrahlen;
                system = "superrare_beams1";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                attachment = muzzle;
                id = 18;
                name = "Kreisendes Friedenszeichen";
                system = "superrare_circling_peacesign";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                attachment = muzzle;
                id = 19;
                name = "Kreisendes Herz";
                system = "superrare_circling_heart";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                id = 20;
                name = "Karten-Briefmarken";
                system = "stamp_spin";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 0;
                attachment = "cig_drg_smoke";
                id = 28;
                name = "Eleganter Rauch";
                system = "drg_pipe_smoke";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                id = 29;
                name = "St\U00fcrmischer Sturm";
                system = "unusual_storm";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                id = 30;
                name = "Eisiger Sturm";
                system = "unusual_blizzard";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                id = 31;
                name = "Muttern & Bolzen";
                system = "unusual_orbit_nutsnbolts";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                id = 32;
                name = "Kreisende Planeten";
                system = "unusual_orbit_planets";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                id = 33;
                name = "Kreisendes Feuer";
                system = "unusual_orbit_fire";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                id = 34;
                name = Blubbern;
                system = "unusual_bubbles";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                id = 35;
                name = Rauchen;
                system = "unusual_smoking";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                id = 36;
                name = Dampfen;
                system = "unusual_steaming";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                id = 37;
                name = "Brennende Laterne";
                system = "unusual_orbit_jack_flaming";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                id = 38;
                name = "Bew\U00f6lkter Mond";
                system = "unusual_fullmoon_cloudy";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                id = 39;
                name = "Blubbernder Kessel";
                system = "unusual_bubbles_green";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                id = 40;
                name = "Schauriges, kreisendes Feuer";
                system = "unusual_orbit_fire_dark";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                attachment = muzzle;
                id = 43;
                name = Messersturm;
                system = "unusual_storm_knives";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                attachment = muzzle;
                id = 44;
                name = "Nebliger Sch\U00e4del";
                system = "unusual_skull_misty";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                attachment = muzzle;
                id = 45;
                name = Herbstmond;
                system = "unusual_fullmoon_cloudy_green";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                attachment = muzzle;
                id = 46;
                name = "Es ist ein Geheimnis f\U00fcr jeden";
                system = "unusual_fullmoon_cloudy_secret";
            },
                        {
                "attach_to_rootbone" = 1;
                attachment = muzzle;
                id = 47;
                name = "St\U00fcrmische 13. Stunde";
                system = "unusual_storm_spooky";
            }
        );
        attributes =         (
                        {
                "attribute_class" = "mult_dmg";
                defindex = 1;
                "description_format" = "value_is_percentage";
                "description_string" = "%s1%\U00a0geringerer Schaden";
                "effect_type" = negative;
                hidden = 0;
                "max_value" = "0.85";
                "min_value" = "0.95";
                name = "damage penalty";
                "stored_as_integer" = 0;
            },
                        {
                "attribute_class" = "mult_dmg";
                defindex = 2;
                "description_format" = "value_is_percentage";
                "description_string" = "+%s1%\U00a0Schadensbonus";
                "effect_type" = positive;
                hidden = 0;
                "max_value" = "1.1";
                "min_value" = "1.05";
                name = "damage bonus";
                "stored_as_integer" = 0;
            },
                        {
                "attribute_class" = "mult_clipsize";
                defindex = 3;
                "description_format" = "value_is_percentage";
                "description_string" = "%s1%\U00a0Magazingr\U00f6\U00dfe";
                "effect_type" = negative;
                hidden = 0;
                "max_value" = "0.75";
                "min_value" = "0.9";
                name = "clip size penalty";
                "stored_as_integer" = 0;
            },
                        {
                "attribute_class" = "mult_clipsize";
                defindex = 4;
                "description_format" = "value_is_percentage";
                "description_string" = "+%s1%\U00a0Magazingr\U00f6\U00dfe";
                "effect_type" = positive;
                hidden = 0;
                "max_value" = "1.1";
                "min_value" = "1.05";
                name = "clip size bonus";
                "stored_as_integer" = 0;
            },
                        {
                "attribute_class" = "mult_postfiredelay";
                defindex = 5;
                "description_format" = "value_is_inverted_percentage";
                "description_string" = "%s1%\U00a0niedrigere Schussfrequenz";
                "effect_type" = negative;
                hidden = 0;
                "max_value" = "1.25";
                "min_value" = "1.05";
                name = "fire rate penalty";
                "stored_as_integer" = 0;
            },
                        {
                "attribute_class" = "mult_postfiredelay";
                defindex = 6;
                "description_format" = "value_is_inverted_percentage";
                "description_string" = "+%s1%\U00a0h\U00f6here Schussfrequenz";
                "effect_type" = positive;
                hidden = 0;
                "max_value" = "0.9";
                "min_value" = "0.95";
                name = "fire rate bonus";
                "stored_as_integer" = 0;
            },
                        {
                "attribute_class" = "mult_medigun_healrate";
                defindex = 7;
                "description_format" = "value_is_percentage";
                "description_string" = "%s1%\U00a0Heilungsrate";
                "effect_type" = negative;
                hidden = 0;
                "max_value" = "0.8";
                "min_value" = "0.95";
                name = "heal rate penalty";
                "stored_as_integer" = 0;
            },
                        {
                "attribute_class" = "mult_medigun_healrate";
                defindex = 8;
                "description_format" = "value_is_percentage";
                "description_string" = "+%s1%\U00a0Heilungsrate";
                "effect_type" = positive;
                hidden = 0;
                "max_value" = "1.15";
                "min_value" = "1.05";
                name = "heal rate bonus";
                "stored_as_integer" = 0;
            },
```

*My Question is:* How do I get the name of an item at an index ?

I tried

```
[[[[news objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"items"]objectAtIndex:2] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

News is the array that contains the Data !

Hope you can help
Tim

Comment: I have download your JSON file it does not contain any entry with key name "items".

Comment: "I have an NSArray created from a JSON file". No, you have a dictionary, containing several keys...

Comment: Yeha in the file but the file is the output of news and news are declared as nsarray in my header

Comment: Can you specify what value are you trying to get? Is it `"name"`, `"item-name"`, something else? In the file, on what line is a typical example of what you're trying to get?

Comment: You need to learn how to read JSON.  Please study the (very brief) ["reference manual"](http://www.json.org/).  What you have is not an array but several nested "objects" (which, when parsed into Objective-C objects, become dictionaries).

Comment: In the new code you added there is nothing called `"items"`

Comment: (Hint, when you dump an Objective-C representation of JSON, dictionaries/"objects" are bracketed by `{}` and arrays are bracketed by `()`.  In JSON array are bracketed by `[]`.)

Comment: (Another hint.  Objective-C doesn't care a whit whether you called an object an NSArray, if it's actually an NSDictionary (and you can sneak the error past the compiler).  Type is detected at runtime, so even though your variable is called an "NSArray", the pointer it contains is an "NSDictionary".)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a dictionary consisting of several arrays of dictionaries. I think you want something like this... (edit: like mentioned in the comments, it depends which array of dictionaries you need to get the name from, as there seem to be several to chose from in the results).

```
NSArray *array = [resultDictionary objectForKey:@"attribute_controlled_attached_particles"];

for (NSDictionary *aDictionary in array){
    NSString *name = [aDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
   // do what you want with the string...
   // could be useful if you for instance need to make an array of all the names
}
```

Or of course:

```
NSString *someString = [[array objectAtIndex:3] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: Sorry but your first code returns null and the second one gives me an error (i have added my whole code in my original post)

Comment: I haven't got detailed knowledge of your code outside of what you are displaying. If you create the resultDictionary instance I'm using in my code so that it is equal to where you state "result = ..." etc. I believe it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have got a dictionary containing another dictionary (not a smart idea), so you should get the dictionary inside it using the objectForKey: selector. Now if you are able to get the key-value of a dictionary, you wouldn't have problems doing it N times.

The [] operator allows you to access the values of an array/dictionary and it works like objectAtIndex:/valueForKey: . Here is how to do it:

```
NSDictionary* result= json[@"result"];
NSArray* acabArray= result[@"attribute_controlled_attached_particles"];
for(NSDictionary* acabDict in acabArray)
{
    NSNumber* num= acabDict[@"attach_to_rootbone"];
    NSString* name= acabDict[@"name"];
    // Obtain also the other key-values in a similar way
    // Do what you want with these values, I suggest to build a custom
    // object to hold all these values, and put every object in a mutable array.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an `NSDictionary` containing a `NSDictionary` (keyed by "result") containing an `NSArray` (keyed by "attribute_controlled_attached_particles"). To get this containg array, you need to do:

```
NSArray *resultArray = [[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"result"] objectForKey:@"attribute_controlled_attached_particles"];
```

Inside the `resultArray`, you have an ordered list of dictionaries representing news items. So, to get the "name" string for the first index, do

```
NSDictionary *itemDictionary = [resultArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *name = [itemDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
```

To enumerate all items, you need to iterate through the resultArray.